# Normal random variable $X$ and the cdf of $Y=aX+b$

Tags: probability

> Given normal random variable $X$ and $Y=aX+b$, the cumulative distribution function for $Y$ is $F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)$. Show that $F_{Y}(y)=P(X\leq\frac{y-b}{a})$.

I know that the cdf of the normal random variable is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-t^2/2}dt$ but I'm not sure how to go from there to the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is almost nothing to do. We have 
$$P(Y\le y)=P(aX+b \le y)=P(aX \le y-b).$$
If $a$ is **positive**, then
$$P(aX\le y-b)=P\left(X\le \frac{y-b}{a}\right),$$
and we are finished.  Normality has nothing to do with the result.

**Remark:** The expression $\frac{y-b}{a}$  obviously makes no sense if $a=0$.  If $a <0$, the inequality of the problem is *false*. In that case, since dividing by a negative *reverses* inequalities, we get
$$P(Y\le y)=P\left(X\ge \frac{y-b}{a}\right).$$